# Customize add colleagues email template

Tags: alert, development, social

I need to customize the mail that is sent when I add a colleague in "my site" profile on SharePoint 2010 Environment.

The below URL says it is not possible however want to check if you have any other way of doing it.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/4b6ffbc5-3942-450e-b11b-9754551873aa/

Answer (score 1):

That is correct.  This is a list of alerts that can be modified and how to modify them ( the correct way to stay supported).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802738.aspx